# How to easily solve this trigonometric equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Given equation:
$$\frac{\sin(x) + \sin(5x) - \sin(3x)}{\cos(x) + \cos(5x) - \cos(3x)} = \tan(3x),$$
what is the easiest way to solve it? I know it can be solved by expanding each $\sin(nx)$ and $\cos(nx)$ terms, but is there an easier way?

Comment: I would start by saying $x = (3x - 2x)$ and $5x = 3x + 2x$ expanding those two, expecting some things to cancel.

Comment: Oh gosh, how could I have been so blind. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Simply write
$$ \sin x+\sin 5x=\sin(3x-2x) + \sin(3x+2x)=2\sin 3x\cos 2x$$
and similarly fot $\cos x+\cos 5x$.

Comment: Is there any rule when I should apply identities of those kind?

Comment: Yes: it's when you have arcs in arithmetic progression. For instance, in the case of $\sin x+\sin 3x+\sin 5x+\sin 7x$, you would rewrite it as $\sin(4x-3x)+\sin(4x-x)+\sin(4x+x)+\sin(4x33x)$ (note in this case, $4x$ doesn't appear anywhere in the initial formula), to be able to apply the factorisation formulae deduced from the addition formulae.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac { 2\sin { \left( \frac { x+5x }{ 2 }  \right) \cos { \left( \frac { x-5x }{ 2 }  \right) -\sin { \left( 3x \right)  }  }  }  }{ 2\cos { \left( \frac { x+5x }{ 2 }  \right) \cos { \left( \frac { x-5x }{ 2 }  \right)  } -\cos { \left( 3x \right)  }  }  } =\frac { \sin { \left( 3x \right) \left( 2\cos { 2x-1 }  \right)  }  }{ \cos { \left( 3x \right) \left( 2\cos { 2x-1 }  \right)  }  } =\tan  (3x)$$